# Free tent camping location close to Adelaide?

Tags: online-resources, australia, camping

I would like to be able to camp without fees for a week outside of Adelaide City, in South Australia, being able to walk, cycle or take public transport into town within an hour.

Not wishing to spend on a paid mobile application listing campsites, I'd like to find free information online.

Comment: Not an answer, this link might help: https://www.weekendnotes.com/free-camping-spots-sa/ (As I do not know the quality of the information I do not feel right to copy details.)

Comment: @Willeke The closest that anyone of those spots is to Adelaide is 2 hours by *private* transport.  They are locations out in the bush, not near the city centre.

Comment: If you are Aboriginal you can camp in the city parks for free.

Answer (score 3):

Clarendon Campground might be your only option, that I can find.

FindaCamp literally only shows one within 25km of the city - [Clarendon](http://www.findacamp.com.au/camp-site.php?pc=ADELAIDE_SA_5000&dis=25&camp=382).  A permit is required, however.

There used to be no camping signs up, but from comments on [this list of sites](https://australiancaravans.com.au/library/05/2014/free-camping-adelaide-region/), these signs have been removed.

Further, on [the same australiancaravans page](https://australiancaravans.com.au/library/05/2014/free-camping-adelaide-region/), locals have listed a bunch of their favourite free camping sites.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you're really going to struggle with this one.

Like most big Australian cities, Adelaide heavily restricts camping within a sizeable radius of its city centre, and it's even hard to find paid camps outside of caravan parks.

Unless you want to camp illegally - I can't recommend this, but plenty of people do - the closest free campsite is close to an hour from Adelaide by private vehicle.

What's more, most of the closest options are simple highway rest areas. Sure, they offer a place to sleep, but I certainly wouldn't want to stay in one for a week.

Here are a few of the closest free camping options:

**Nairne Rest Area -** While you won't find comfort here, it's arguably the closest free camp to the city centre. It's 40km southeast of Adelaide, which you could almost cover in an hour on a decent bike.

**Lower Light Hotel Free Camping -** This one's just over 50km north of Adelaide, and it's definitely worth checking out. It's a rather basic campground, but it sits back off the highway a little and offers a peaceful camping experience.

**Robinsons Hill Walk-In Camping -** This free campsite is situated 87km south of Adelaide, which is feasibly within biking distance for some. It's a small, walk-in camp that's 300m from the closest road, and it offers beautiful scenery and a peaceful vibe.

**Red Banks Conservation Park Campground -** You will have to travel a little further to this free camp, as it sits 180km north of Adelaide. I recently wrote an article outlining the [best free campsites in Australia](https://www.campingaussie.com.au/guides/best-free-camping-sites-in-australia), and Red Banks was among the top three options in South Australia.

All that said, I'd highly recommend paying a few dollars for the [WikiCamps app](https://www.wikicamps.com.au/), as it lists literally every place you can safely camp in Australia.